# How to upload a file using Ajax on POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know, the topics aren't missing on this subject but bear with me. I'd like to upload a file to the server using Ajax or an equivalent.

```
# html
<form method="post" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %} # django security
  <input id="image_file" type="file" name="image_file">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
# javascript
$(document).on('submit', '#Form', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', $('#image_file').get(0).files);

  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'my_url',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data:{
          logo:form_data,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), # django security
      },
  });
});
```

---

```
# views.py (server side)
def myFunction(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file = request.FILES
        ...
...
```

I guess there's an issue with the way I configured the ajax function since on debug mode, every data are returned except the `logo`.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking back, the older answer is unpractical and not recommended. `async: false` pauses the entire Javascript to simply upload a file, *you are likely firing other functions during the upload*.

If you are using JQuery solely for the use of `ajax`, then I recommend using `axios`:

```
const axios = require('axios');

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('imageFile', document.querySelector('#image_file').files[0]);

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'your_url',
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": CSRF_TOKEN, # django security
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    # success
});
```

[Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) Documentation

---

**Jquery/Ajax answer:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('imageFile', $('#image_file')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', CSRF_TOKEN); # django security

$.ajax({
   url : 'your_url',
   type : 'POST',
   data : formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success : function(data) {
       # success
   }
});
```

[Jquery/Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Documentation

Answer (score 15):

The below method works for me, it will submit all form value as `serialize()`. You will get all form input's inside `request.POST` and logo `request.FILES`

**Try this:**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#creationOptionsForm', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var form_data = new FormData($('#creationOptionsForm')[0]);
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/designer/results/',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      data : form_data,
      success: function(response){

      }
  });
});
```

**Update:**

basically `async:false` will do ajax request and stop executing further js code till the time request get complete, because upload file might take some time to upload to server.

While `cache` will force browser to not cache uploaded data to get updated data in ajax request

**[Official Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) here**

Comment: You do not need `async: false` anymore (on the contrary: if you set it, you'll get a warning in the Chrome console)

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Update: We can use native fetch in all current browsers

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('imageFile', document.getElementById('image_file').files[0]);

fetch('your_url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": CSRF_TOKEN, // Django security  }, // remove for a normal post
})
.then(response => response.json()) // or response.text() if the server returns plain text
.then(data => console.log(data)) // replace with whatever you want to happen after the upload
.catch(error =>console.error('Error:', error));
```