# Problem with uploading a image via Ajax Call in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to upload an image via Ajax call but I am not able to upload the image. Kindly check my code what I am doing wrong:

HTML File:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="photo1" id="photo1" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile2(event)">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="createDocsVerify()">Update Details</button>
```

Ajax Call:

```
<script>
 function createDocsVerify () {

  var data = {
   'photo1'     : jQuery('#photo1').val(),
  }; 

  //Ajax call Start Here
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/myproject/adminseller/sellerdocsverify.php',
    method : 'POST',
    data : data,
    success : function(data){

    if (data != 'passed') { 
     jQuery('#modal_errors_3').html(data);
    }

    if (data == 'passed') {

     jQuery('#modal_errors_3').html("");
     location.reload();
   }
   },
   error : function (){alert("Something went wrong.");},

   });    

  }
  </script>
```

Php File: sellerdocsverify.php

```
if (isset($_POST['photo1'])) {
   $photo1 = sanitize($_POST['photo1']);
   // var_dump Output: string(20) "C:\fakepath\0553.jpg" 
 }


 $errors = array();
  $required = array(
   'photo1'  => 'Please select Photo 1',
);



// check if all required fileds are fill out
foreach ($required as $field => $display) {
 if (empty($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '') {
  $errors[] = $display.'.';
 }
 }


$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
$photoNameArray = array();
$tmpLoc = array();
$uploadPath = array();



**// Here is the problem**
$name1 = $_FILES['photo1']['name']; // Here is the problem
Var_dump($name1); // OUTPUT: NULL
**// Here is the problem**



$nameArray = explode('.',$name1);
$fileName = $nameArray[0];
$fileExt = $nameArray[1];  

$mime = $_FILES['photo1']['type'];
$mimeType = $mime[0];
$mimeExt = $mime[1];
$tmpLoc = $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['photo1']['size'];

$uploadName = md5(microtime().$j).'.'.$fileExt;
$uploadPath = BASEURL.'images/products/'.$uploadName;

if ($mimeType != 'image') {
 $errors[] = 'The file must be an image.';
}



if (!empty($errors)) {
  echo display_errors($errors);
 }else{
  echo 'passed';

   // upload file and insert into database
  if ($photoCount > 0) {        
    move_uploaded_file($tmpLoc1, $uploadPath1);
   }

$insertSql = "INSERT INTO docTable  (`photo1`)
VALUES ('$photo1')";
$db->query($insertSql);

$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;">Data Saved Successfully!</span>';


}
?>
```

Kind check my code and suggest what I am doing wrong, am I doing something wrong in Ajax call or in php, I am getting the value in $photo1.

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: How do you know you're doing something wrong? Use your browser's inspector to check the POST request. Does everything get sent properly?

Comment: Also check this question and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44708023/1255289

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some special "things" to upload files via AJAX. You need to create a FormData object and manually add the file data to it, and also set the contentType, processData and cache options of your AJAX call to `false`. Your javascript should look like this:

```
<script>
function createDocsVerify() {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var file = jQuery('#photo1').prop('files')[0];
    formdata.append('photo1', file);

    //Ajax call Start Here
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/myproject/adminseller/sellerdocsverify.php',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formdata,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != 'passed') {
                jQuery('#modal_errors_3').html(data);
            }
            if (data == 'passed') {
                jQuery('#modal_errors_3').html("");
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong.");
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

That should upload the photo.

Comment: What "special things" should the OP do? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This is one of those instances where I know what to do, but not exactly the why. To upload files I know you have to use the FormData object, I know you have to set the cache, processData and contentType options to false, etc., but that's it.

Comment: Then explain that in your answer. Right now the OP is having to guess what you did and what you changed, provided they know how to diff code.

Comment: Ok, there you go.

Comment: @Jose Thanks for the answer but in php it says $required = array(
   'photo1'  => 'Please select Photo 1',
);
Please select photo1 and file is not an image while now I am getting filename and fileext is: png

Comment: `$_POST['photo1']` is always empty! You're only sending the file, which is stored in the `$_FILES['photo1']` variable. You should remove the `required` array in your PHP.

Comment: @jose Thanks for the answer. I have removed required array but now I have only one error if ($mimeType != 'image') {
  $errors[] = 'The file must be an image.';
} . The file must be an image. While I have submit png file, I also submit jpg and jpeg file but it always saying The file must be an image.

Comment: That's because the mime type is never "image". It's, depending on the type, "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", etc. If you want to check if `$mimeType` against "image", you could use only the first five characters, like this: `$mimeType = substr($mime[0],0,5)`