# Laravel upload file using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, file-upload, nullable

I'm trying to create upload function in Laravel 5.7 using Ajax request. 
I'm getting null value in the database after writing this code. So, all other data are being inserted except the file that is returning empty value.

tasks.blade.php

```
<form method="post" id="addTask_form" name="addtask" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      .......................
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>File</label>
                 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            </div>
            .............


        </div>                 

      <div class="modal-footer">
       ................
      </div>
      </form>
```

TasksController.php

```
 function postdata(Request $request)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        .......
        'file' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',    
        'status' => 'required',

        ]);

   .............
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        foreach ($validation->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
        {
            ...........
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($request->get('button_action') == 'insert')
        {


            if($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()){
                $file = $request->file('file');
                $file_name = str_random(30) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move(base_path() . '/assets/img', $file_name);
            }
            $task = new Task($request->input());

            $task->save();


    }


    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $error_array,
        'success'   =>  $success_output
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the javascript code you use to submit the form?

Comment: `$('#addTask_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('postdataroute')}}",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data.error.length > 0) 
..................`

Comment: please add your javascript code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not upload image using `serialize()`. you need to use `FormData()` with these properties;

```
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
```

```js
    var data = new FormData($('#addTask_form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('postdataroute')}}",
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }      
    });
```

1. if you don't want to send csrf token

then

```
    app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

and add this route's url to the except array

```
    protected $except = [
    'your route url'
    ];
```

2. if want

then add in head

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in script

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) method to upload a file using `Ajax` Request on `POST`

```
$(document).on('submit', '#yourFormId', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var form_data = new FormData($('#yourFormId')[0]); // this method will send the file request and the post data 
  form_data.append("_token","{{csrf_token()}}") //for csrf token
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'{{route('yourRoute')}}',
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      data : form_data,
      success: function(response){

      }
  });
});
```

basically `async:false` will do ajax request and stop executing further js code till the time request get complete, because upload file might take some time to upload to server.

While `cache` will force browser to not cache uploaded data to get updated data in ajax request

Referrer on [How to upload file using Ajax On Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708023/how-to-upload-a-file-using-ajax-on-post)